# Passing a string variable to Fullcalendar as event source url not working?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm not quite sure if this is a pure Javascript issue, or just fullcalendar (considering how it likes to be temperamental).

Since I wanted to pass a unique JSON feed URL for each user, I stated my string variable with the url outside the fullcalendar function as a global, and have also tried passing it into the function.

```
eventURL = idString + '/path_to/json'
```

...

```
eventSources: [
    {
      events: function(start, end, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: eventURL,
            dataType: 'json',

            data: {
                start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),
            },
            success: function(doc) {
                var events = eval(doc);
                callback(events);
            }
         });
      }
}]
```

I've successfully tested the fullcalendar function by hardcoding the URL, so I know that's not the problem.  I assume it has something to do with how the call is made with the url via ajax, and not formatting correctly.  Not quite sure.

Why won't Fullcalendar just shut up and take my variable?

Comment: So you're setting `eventURL` before initializing full calendar? Are you able to see the ajax request made in your browser network debug?

Comment: I would say probably is your var its not getting populated first...it makes no sense why shouldnt work. Try to wrap the var in a function and return it with the url...i guess

Comment: by the way try this `var eventURL = idString + '/path_to/json'`

Comment: Yea, go figure.  Yes, eventURL is initialized beforehand.  I've tried wrapping both in functions and passing between, but no luck.  I'm sure it's something trivial, I was just curious if fullcalendar required something I didn't know about.  I'll double check on Shaded's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the ajax way of calling the events but on my fullcalendar I use my JSON feed like this:

```
events: {
    url: '../CalendarEventsServlet?ids=' + selectedValues
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't remember what the problem was, but it was probably something trivial like this.